# MVC 4 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is where I'm getting my error.

```
@foreach(var entry in ViewBag.Entries){...}
```

I stepped through the program after entering values into a form.

The Entries are hitting the dB and in my controller it showed that the linq code hit the DB but when I returned the view, the object wasn't found?

here is the code in my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var mostRecentEntries =
    (from entry in _db.Entries
     orderby entry.DateAdded descending
     select entry).Take(20);
     return View();
}
```

If it'll help you this is coming straight out of a book *ASP.net mvc 4 in Action* by the Manning company around page 34.

Comment: If you down vote please comment down the reason why you are down voting. It will help new users to improve their question.

Answer (score 5):

As the error is trying to tell you, `ViewBag.Entries` is null.

If you want to use something in `ViewBag`, you need to put it there in the controller.

Comment: it is in the controller when I step through it

Comment: Actually, it's `ViewBag` that is null.  The exception occurs when he tries to dereference it by accessing the `Entries` property.

Comment: @Daniel, the only possible cause of a null reference exception in the line you have posted is `ViewBag`.  Is the exception coming from the loop body? What are the loop's contents?

Comment: <section class="contact">
        <header>
            <h3>@entry.Message</h3>
        </header>
        <p>
            Posted by @entry.Name on      @entry.DateAdded.ToLongDateString();
        </p>
    </section>

Comment: sorry, let me try that again, the error is happening when it hits ViewBag.Entries,

Comment: Then `ViewBag` is null, as @SLaks said.

Comment: if it helps, after it leaves the controller it goes to a page called _ViewStart then hops to the top of my index page where it has this at the top

Comment: @{   ViewBag.Title = "List"; }

Comment: Try googling 'viewbag is null' and see if you find a solution.  Without more context it is impossible for us to know.

Comment: I figured it out, the problem was I didn't set the ViewBag.Entries = to my LINQ query, so it never picked it up in my Index page after I returned the view, thanks for helping out though

Comment: @PeterGluck: Wrong.  `ViewBag` can never be null.  The problem is that `Entries` is null, which the `foreach` then chokes on.  (when calling `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah, that makes sense.  I stand corrected. Thank you for the insight!